# How does prepared statement skip the escape characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, prepared-statement

I have a query like this

```
   val ps = con.prepareStatement(s"SELECT * from employee where name LIKE ?")
    ps.setString(1, "%" + searchTerm + "%")
    val rs = ps.executeQuery()
```

and when I print the prepared statement, I get

```
:HikariProxyPreparedStatement@710925960 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: SELECT * from employee where name LIKE '%abc''%'
```

If i run the SELECT query in the mysql editor, I get error because the query is malformed.
But when I run the prepared statement, I don't get error. Why is that ?

What query does prepared statement run, if the above query gives error? I see an empty result set, which means the query did not fail. Does the prepared statement change the query by itself ?

Comment: I would guess that `searchstring is `abc'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a prepared statement, the values of parameters are not combined with the query until *after* it is parsed. So there's no way any special characters in the parameter value can upset the syntax of the query.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but what does above query be executed as, if it had executed with whatever It printed, it would have failed . But it did not fail